# Linked List Choke Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, linked-list

I have an assignment on Linked List, and the name of the game is to add words from a string into an array implemented linked list, which is alphabetically ordered with pointers.

However, when I run the following code, the Python Shell gets stuck and no results come back. Please help! Thank you!

I think the error may be in here, but im not sure why no results come back :/

```
if self.NextFree != len(self.array):
            prev = curr = self.Start
            while self.array[curr].word < nword:
                prev = curr
                curr = self.array[curr].pointer
```

The full code is here: (Sorry if its long im a beginner! :))

```
class ListNode:
def __init__(self,word,pointer,count = 1):
    self.word = word
    self.pointer = pointer
    self.count = count


class LinkedList:
def __init__(self):
    self.array = []
    self.Start = -1
    self.NextFree = self.Start + 1

def Initialise(self):
    MAX = 30
    for i in range(MAX-1):
        self.array.append(ListNode('',i+1))
    self.array.append(ListNode(' ', -1))     #last node has pointer of -1

def Display(self):
    print(self.Start, self.NextFree, len(self.array),sep = ' ')
    print("Index  ", "Content  ", "Count  ", "Pointer")
    for i in range(len(self.array)):
        print('{0:<7}{1:<11}{2:<8}{3:}'.format(i, self.array[i].word, self.array[i].count, self.array[i].pointer))

def IsEmpty(self):
    return self.Start == -1

def IsFull(self):
    return self.NextFree == len(self.array)

def Update(self,nword):        #nword = newword      
    if self.IsEmpty(): 
        self.Start = 0
        self.array[0].word = nword
        self.NextFree += 1
    else:
        if self.NextFree != len(self.array):
            prev = curr = self.Start
            while self.array[curr].word < nword:
                prev = curr
                curr = self.array[curr].pointer
            if self.array[curr].word == nword:
                self.array[curr].count += 1
            else:
                self.array[prev].pointer = self.NextFree
                self.array[self.NextFree].word = nword
                self.array[self.NextFree].pointer = curr
                self.NextFree += 1
        else:
            print ("f")

def DisplayT(self):
    for i in range(len(self.array)):
        print(self.array[i].word)

l = LinkedList()
l.Initialise()
##with open("Story.txt") as file:
##    for words in file.readline().split(" "):   #story.txt is single line
##        l.Update(words)
story = "she sells seashells by the seashore the shells she sells are surely seashells so if she sells shells on the seashore i am sure she sells seashore shells peter piper picked a peck of pickled peppers did peter piper pick a peck of pickled peppers if peter piper picked a peck of pickled peppers where is the peck of pickled peppers peter piper picked"
for words in story:
    l.Update(words)
l.Display()
```

Answer (score 0):

As this is an assignment question. I will try to guide you to an answer!

Please substitute this in your code (on Update function) and see what prints out =)

```
while self.array[curr].word < nword:
                print(self.array[curr].word)
                print(nword)
                print('loop')
                prev = curr
                curr = self.array[curr].pointer
```

Try to realize what is wrong with this while loop by examining this print and comment back here. I will edit with a better answer by then!

But basically you are falling into an infinite loop. Try to figure out why!

Comment: Hmm. It prints out a lot of 'f's and only a select few words on repeat (such as (she the shells surely).                   It looks like this:
f
f
she
the
loop
f
f
she
the
loop
f
she
shells
loop
f
f
f
f
she
surely
loop
shells
surely                     And the display shows this:     0 29 30
Index   Content   Count   Pointer
0      she        1       28
1      the        3       27
2      shells     1       24
3      surely     1       22
4      surely     1       26
5      so         1       20
..(char limit) So im not sure where the other words went lol

Comment: Hmm. I tried printing self.array[prev].word in the loop too. Seems that 'she' is both the prev and curr word for at least 10 iterations. Not sure why but seems like the new words are not being properly inserted. Also it alternates between 'f' and the loop, which is what confuses me. How can it alternate between self.IsEmpty()?